# ng-if only deletes innerHTML in my table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am making a custom directive which will paginate and make my table sortable.  I am trying to make it so that multiple data types will work with the sorting with no effort from the user.  Here is my problematic html in my templateUrl:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in cndPaginatedObject track by $index">
            <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index" ng-if="!isValidDate(row[cndTableHeaders[$index]])">
                {{row[cndTableHeaders[$index]]}}
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index" ng-if="isValidDate(row[cndTableHeaders[$index]])">
                {{row[cndTableHeaders[$index]] | date: cndDateFormat}}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I would prefer to use ng-if as opposed to ng-show/hide because it would unnecessarily duplicate DOM elements with ng-show/hide and just not show them.  I have tried both ways, but I get the same result either way.  The content of columns with dates in them don't show up, but the td itself is still there taking up space.  So, I end up having three headers for columns and more than three columns.  As far as I was aware, ng-if is supposed to remove the entire element from the DOM.

here is my other code of significance:

```
        scope.isValidDate = (data) => {
            var timestamp = Date.parse(data);
            return !(isNaN(timestamp));
        }
```

As for cndPaginatedObject, it is just an array of objects with multiple strings contained within.  Thank you for any help in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Just thought I would also add that the cndTableHeaders is literally the table headers.  cndPaginatedObject uses the table headers as the keys to each of the values.  This way they show up in the proper order in the table.

Comment: So in short you're looking for a directive that deletes all the html rather than just the stuff inside <td>?

Comment: Yes, I want the entire td to be removed along with the content inside of it if the parameter given returns false.  As far as I know, that is what ng-if does.  If I were to type:

<h1 ng-if="false">remove me</h1>

that <h1> should not even show up in the markup of the page.  Just a comment in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do what you're doing better without the need to produce extra doms and looping a ng-repeat twice

A better way to do what you want to do is

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in cndPaginatedObject track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index">
            {{(!isValidDate(row[cndTableHeaders[$index]])) ? row[cndTableHeaders[$index]] : row[cndTableHeaders[$index]] | date: cndDateFormat}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Or add a span inside the  with the ng-if logic

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in cndPaginatedObject track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index"">
            <span ng-if="!isValidDate(row[cndTableHeaders[$index]])>
                {{row[cndTableHeaders[$index]]}}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="isValidDate(row[cndTableHeaders[$index]])">
                {{row[cndTableHeaders[$index]] | date: cndDateFormat}}
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Alternatively you could create your own filter which checks if date is valid and then using the date filter to filter it.

Comment: The ng-repeat and ng-if in your original code are awkward.  I agree with the last sentence that you just add a filter to the ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  I like both options and I tried them both.  It did end up fixing the problem with the extra columns, but now for some reason the date is not showing up at all. I am trying to figure that out right now.  But my first question was fixed, so +1 for that!